# How to a server to server dialogflow api call?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have a docker container in a swarm running on centOS.
I need to make a dialogflow POST call to do export an dialogflow agent from the docker container.

I tried using dialogflow developer token, it didn't seem to work out.
Also tried making the same call via api using auth token.

`curl --request POST \
  'https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/projects/testProject/agent:export?key=PROJECT_KEY' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{}' \
  --compressed`

Comment: What part does not work?

Comment: the whole part is throwing 401 error

Comment: what I wanted to do was download the key in json and use it

https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/v2-auth-setup

Comment: Does the command work when executed outside of the docker container?